# Executing JS for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

what Im trying to do is - load a html page with iframe'd website, and then remove an element of that website, lets call it '#test'

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone got any ideas how I would go about this? Can't seem to do it in normal .remove() fashion...

Thanks!

Comment: [Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

Comment: From your example: read the answer posted by [VCS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page/2663118#2663118)

Comment: I assume the `iframe` and page you're loading the iframe in are on different domains? In this case, there's very little you can do thanks to the cross domain browser policy, which prevents pages on one domain executed JS on another domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are in **same domain** you can use `window.parent` inside your iframe to load an script and your desired elements and using `eval`ing that script remove the iframe itself

code for inner window aka the iframe:

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.innerHTML = "var removeIframe = function(){document.body.removeChild(document.body.querySelector('iframe'));}"
window.parent.document.body.appendChild(myscript);
window.parent.eval(removeIframe);
```

Comment: what if its on different host?

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy you can not do that

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#test').remove();
```

Comment: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cg(a){return d...a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=d})(window);